# Export Audio in UnityScript

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

I need to export audio in Unity to the user and anything I try isn't working. Sav.Wav.Save doesn't work. Please respond in **UnityScript**.

Comment: I advice you to give your code to use sav.was, and give more log about it. Recently, I use sav.wav too, it worked. And if what you want is export, please the destination folder's permission.